# Parametrize a line in $\mathbb {CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I parametrize a line in  $\mathbb {CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1$?

I've found something call the Segre map, but I do not know how to use it. The only thing I want to know is how they look like; they could be a zero locus of a certain polynomial or something like  that.

And, the other question is, How many lines pass through two given points in $\mathbb {CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1$?

By a line in {CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1$ I mean a copy of  {CP}^1 :)

Thank you.

Comment: Please educate me. What is the definition of a line as a subset of $\Bbb{P}^1\times\Bbb{P}^1$?

Comment: I think is the zero locus of a polynomial, but I do not know, that the question Jyrki Lahtonen, hahahahah how can I see the lines in ℙ1×ℙ1?, but please, do not forget the other one :), I am working in that but still difficult for me :)

Comment: I would like to attempt to answer the other question, but it is kinda difficult as I don't know what you mean by a line in this context :-)

Comment: There is no definition of lines in arbitrary varieties (at least I haven't seen one). But in $\mathbb{P}^n$ we have the notion of a line. And $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^3$ (Segre embedding). But there are lots of embeddings, I think. Therefore I don't know what lines really are ...

Comment: Thank you Jyrki Lahtonen, but I have this: the lines whose slope is infinite are parametrize by [x0:x1]x(ℂℙ^1). May be this can help :)

Comment: Well, in $\Bbb{P}^3$ any pair of points determines a unique line, so if we first embed $\Bbb{P}^1\times\Bbb{P}^1$ into $\Bbb{P}^3$ by any means, won't that turn the question into a dull one?

Comment: I do not undersatnd the question Jyrki Lahtonen, I am sorry but, like you say in USA I am a freshman career :), can you rephrase the quiestion please :)

Comment: Rigth, I got it,but in ℙ^3 a line is the zero locus of a polynomial of the form a0x0+a1x1+a2x2+a3x3, isn't it ?, and then whit segre embedding go from ℙ^3 to ℙ1×ℙ1 and then?.

Comment: In this idea, shall we going to find the inverse Segre map?

Comment: Help me please :( I need your help :) Thank You.